# Angular2. Dynamic component creation

Tags: angular

I have a simple table:

```ts
...
   <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
       <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
       <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
       <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
       <td>
        <a href="#">Add select</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

When user clicks on `Add Select` link I want to create select tag. For dropdown list I use [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select)
So, I have two problems, how to get specific `td` when user clicks `Add select` and how to create select component in that `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ts
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" (click)="addSelect(0)">Add select</a>
    <ng2-select *ngFor="let item in ng2Selects[0]"></ng2-select>
  </td>
   <td>
     <a href="#" (click)="addSelect(1)">Add select</a>
     <ng2-select *ngFor="let item in ng2Selects[1]"></ng2-select>
  </td>
   <td>
```

```ts
ng2Selects = [];
addSelect(index:number) {
  if(this.ng2Selects.length < index) {
    this.ng2Selects[index] = [];
  }
  this.ng2Selects[index].push('dummy');
}
```

Comment: There are can be a lot of select inside one cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I think your didn't get question. I want to create ng2-select itself and add to cell, not options for select.

Comment: Where do you see options in my answer? Did you even try it?

Comment: Oh, didn't get your code at a glance. I will try it asap. Thanks.